# Need a regex to test a specific pattern

Tags: regex

The pattern that I need a regex would be:
A string of numbers separated by a decimal points
The string should not start with a decimal point
No part of the string should start with a 0
However 0 can stand alone 
The string should not start or end with a decimal point

An example would be:
Valid string:
124235.321434.54365436.89293982102.737833.0.111122

Invalid String:
00.000.19101
1.2.3.5.A
.1.2.3.

Comment: What have you tried already? Where are the examples of things you've already investigated to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
([1-9]\d*|0)(\.([1-9]\d*|0))*
```

This should answer all your requirements.